# how to export pie chart to excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, d3.js

Is there a way to export this pie chart [the image] which is created using D3js to excel?

[image]

Comment: So what do you want to export? the image? or the data? if it is the data then what was the data source and how were the results generated?

Comment: I just need to recreate this pie chart in excel, whether I export the image or the data, I just need this pie chart to be exported to excel.